# Python - copy specific file from subfolder to destination, get filename from text file

Tags: python

I want to get my script to read a list of names from a list(txt), then search for those in a selected folder with subfolders, then copy and paste those files to another selected folder. My script running without error but no result.

My script:

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

textFile = ("D:\\Test\\list.txt")
sourceFolder = ("D:\\Test")
destinationFolder = ("D:\\")

filesToFind = []
with open(textFile, "r") as tx:
    for row in tx:
        filesToFind.append(row.strip())

for root, dirs, filename in os.walk(sourceFolder):
    if filename in filesToFind:
        f = os.path.join(root, filename)
        shutil.copy(f, destinationFolder)
```

Comment: Can you print the output for filesToFind?

Comment: Try adding some print statements at key points - for example at the top of the for loop print the values of `filename` and `filesToFind`.

Comment: print(filesToFind)  -- Result ['40-C40-TR140ES005D2-01_r00-A.pdf', '40-C40-TR140ES005D2-01_r00-B.pdf']

Comment: Does the source folder has subfolders in it?

Comment: print(filename) -- Result ['list.txt']
['40-C40-TR140ES005D2-01_r00-A.pdf', '40-C40-TR140ES005D2-01_r00-B.pdf', '45-C45-DM4505221-02_r01-A.pdf', '45-C45-DM4505221-02_r01-B.pdf', '83-C03-DA8300209-01_r02-A.pdf', '83-C03-DA8300209-01_r02-B.pdf', 'EC-01.pdf']
['40-C40-TR140ES005D2-01_r00-1.pdf', '45-C45-DM4505221-02_r01-2.pdf', '83-C03-DA8300209-01_r02-3.pdf', 'EC-011.pdf']
[]

Comment: Sushanta Das yes subfolder have

Comment: So `filename` is a list of the files in the folder, so`filename in filesToFind` Isn’t going to work - you need a for loop over `filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven’t test it but I think this will work - change this:

```
for root, dirs, filename in os.walk(sourceFolder):
    if filename in filesToFind:
        f = os.path.join(root, filename)
        shutil.copy(f, destinationFolder)
```

To this:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(sourceFolder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename in filesToFind:
            f = os.path.join(root, filename)
            shutil.copy(f, destinationFolder)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Same code using glob #
## More efficient and also tested one ##
## One more feature added- checks file name given present or not ##

    import os
    import os.path
    import shutil
    import glob

    textFile = ("D:\\Test\\list.txt")
    sourceFolder = ("D:\Test")
    destinationFolder = ("D:\\")

    f = open(textFile, "r").readlines()
    for i in f:
        ListFile= glob.glob(os.path.join(sourceFolder,"**",i.strip()),recursive=True)
        if len(ListFile):
            print(ListFile[0],destinationFolder,os.path.basename(ListFile[0]))
            destinationfile=os.path.join(destinationFolder,os.path.basename(ListFile[0]))
            shutil.copyfile(ListFile[0],destinationfile)
        else:
            print(i,"-File not found")
```